# How to run sikuli 1.0.1 script from command line

Tags: command-line, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm using Sikuli 1.0.1 installed in F drive in a windows8 64bit system.

I've been trying to run a sikuli script (scriptname.sikuli) directly from command line without having to open sikuli-ide.jar before.
I have search on internet, but it looks like the way to do this differ depending on which version you are using
I have read this without any result:
http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html?highlight=command%20line

I have try all these in command line without result

```
F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikuli\sikuli-ide.jar -r F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikul\scripts\lastone.sikuli

@start F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikul\scripts\lastone.sikuli

java -jar F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikuli\sikuli-ide.jar F:\APPS n DEVICES\2 MACRO RECORDERS\Sikul\scripts\lastone.sikuli
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 2 things: 
- Path to the runIDE.cmd 
- Path to the .sikuli file you would like to run.

For example: Open command prompt and execute the following command:

```
C:\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Sikuli\Colour\White.sikuli
```

If this doesn't work, what is the error you are getting?

You can create a .bat file containing the above command: C:\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Sikuli\Colour\White.sikuli

Say the name of batch file is Test.bat. Just Double click the Test.bat

Answer (score 0):

Running Sikuli scripts from command line

**without arguments**

open command prompt.

type cd "Sikuli directory" and enter

type the following command to run :

runIDE.cmd -r "sikuli script path"

**with argument**

runIDE.cmd -r "sikuli script path" -args "a1" "a2" "a3"

Answer (score 0):

From the SikuliX documentation: [how-to-run-sikulix-from-command-line](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/010-command-line.html#how-to-run-sikulix-from-command-line), the 
`-r` (or equivalent: `--run`) option allows you to run sikulix form a command line.